# Error upgrading android project from kotlin 1.6.10 to 1.7.20

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, upgrade

Im getting this error while upgradig my android project to 1.7.20. Has ayone seen it?

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.DescriptorVisibility.isVisible(org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.scopes.receivers.ReceiverValue, org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.DeclarationDescriptorWithVisibility, org.jetbrains.kotlin.descriptors.DeclarationDescriptor)'

> dagger 2.45
> gradle 7.3.3
> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip

```
'kotlin'                       : '1.7.20',
        'compile_sdk'                  : 33,
        'target_sdk'                   : 33,
        'min_sdk'                      : 23,
        'dagger'                       : '2.45',
        'moshi'                        : '1.13.0',
        'timber'                       : '4.7.0',
        'commontest'                   : '1.0.16',
        'commontestandroid'            : '1.0.35',
        'lintRules'                    : '1.0.8',
        'daggermock'                   : '0.8.5',
        'leak_canary'                  : '2.7',
        'robolectric'                  : '4.8.2',
        'room'                         : '2.5.1',
        'okhttp3'                      : '4.9.3',
        'dfp_facebook_ads'             : '6.8.0.0',
        'facebook_ads'                 : '6.8.0',
        'firebase_21_1_0'              : '21.1.0',
        'play_services_16_0_2'         : '16.0.2',
        'play_services_18_0_1'         : '18.0.1',
        'play_services_20_0_1'         : '20.0.1',
        'google_services_gradle_plugin': '4.3.14',
        'work_manager'                 : '2.7.1',
        'exoplayer'                    : '2.18.6',
        'mockito'                      : '4.11.0',
        'picasso'                      : '2.8',
        'compose'                      : '1.4.2',
```

Expected to get no error while upgrading.